# Does anyone know the name of demons who got the boon from shiva to forever sing his prayers and stay in shiva's ears?

Tags: shiva

Who are the demons who got the boon from shiva to forever sing his prayers and stay in shiva's ears? I believe they formed his earrings, but not sure about that story.